# C# Array of objects, can't set values

Tags: c#, arrays, oop, object

```
class City
{
    string name;

    public string getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String value)
    {
        name = value;
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    City[] arr = new City[1];
    arr[0].setName("New York");
}
```

The problem is that I get "System.NullReferenceException", "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." at the line where I set the name to New York. If I do:

```
City city = new City();
city.setName("New York");
```

I don't get any errors but I want to use an array, since I will be adding more objects. Is this possible in C# because it is in C++? Is the only way to declare 5 objects, set their names and then create an array and put them inside?

Comment: you define the array, but you have to initialize the objects too

Comment: For the duplicate, see section `Array` and `Array Elements`.

Comment: On a side note you should look into using a `Name` [property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx) instead of `getName` and `setName` methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are creating an empty array. You have to initialise the object before assigning it:

```
City[] arr = new City[1];
arr[0] = new City();
arr[0].setName("New York");
```

Comment: Thanks. Guess it's some sort of saving memory, to not declare all the objects unless I actually declare and use them.

Comment: @user2765257 It's because sometimes an empty constructor doesn't exist on class you want to put in an array. That's why you have to call it manually.

Answer (score 1):

This line just creates an array with one element.

```
City[] arr = new City[1];
```

The element is null.

You need to assign it a value

```
arr[0] = new City();
```

Then you can access it.

```
arr[0].setName("New York");
```